# change active or selected state of list item using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following list and want to be able to set the active state to on when I click any of them.  Right now, the hover works and when I click on them the active works except for when I click anywhere else on the page the active state goes away.  Is there a way with jQuery to set the state to active?

```
<ul id="cat-tabs">
  <li><a class="tab1" href="javascript:showTab(1);">Live Music</a></li>
  <li><a class="tab2" href="javascript:showTab(2);">Arts &amp; Theatre</a></li>
  <li><a class="tab3" href="javascript:showTab(3);">Classes &amp; Workshops</a></li>
  <li><a class="tab4" href="javascript:showTab(4);">Health &amp; Fitness</a></li>
  <li><a class="tab5" href="javascript:showTab(5);">Food &amp; Drink</a></li>
  <li><a class="tab6" href="javascript:showTab(6);">Happy Hour</a></li>
</ul>
```

and the CSS

```
#cat {
display: block;
float: left;
width: 100%;
border-bottom-width: 4px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-color: #af0c07;
margin-top: 12px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.navigation {
font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
}

#cat-tabs {
font-size: 0.96em;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 12px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 12px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: -14px;
}

#cat-tabs li {
float: left; /* LTR */
list-style: none;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 1px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 1px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 1px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 1px;
}

#cat-tabs a {
color: #333;
background: #d1d2d4;
float: left; /* LTR */
height: 2.2em;
line-height: 2.2em;
padding: 0 0.8em;
text-decoration: none;
-khtml-border-radius-topleft: 8px;
-khtml-border-radius-topright: 8px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 8px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
border-top-left-radius: 8px;
border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}

#cat-tabs a:hover,
#cat-tabs a:focus {
color: #FFFFFF;
background: #af0c07;
}

#cat-tabs a:hover {
-webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: 0.3s ease;
-ms-transition: 0.3s ease;
-o-transition: 0.3s ease;
transition: 0.3s ease;
}

#cat-tabs a:active {
color: #FFFFFF;
background: #af0c07;
}

#cat-tabs li a.active {
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #3d3b3c;
-khtml-border-radius-topleft: 8px;
-khtml-border-radius-topright: 8px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 8px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
border-top-left-radius: 8px;
border-top-right-radius: 8px;
border-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: rest of your javascript code and show it in a jsfiddle or using code inserter in the stackoverflow this is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tz05bmq0/ add ur javascript code and update it

Comment: Check out the answer and if you find it is what you are looking for accept it  as answer and then upvote it

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery! 
This code always add an active class, that a element you clicked. After that, you can add specialcss to the active element.

For example:#cat-tabs a.active{background:red;}

Try this code:

```
$("#cat-tabs a").click(function(){
   $("#cat-tabs a").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Ann the guy also want to keep the active state continued on keypress on body ie outside of the menu

Comment: Ok i understand. But i think this is one approach to solving the problem. It isn't possible with use css only. So he must use jquery. If he uses this code, that solve his problem.

Answer (score 0):

> What I did was to just track which anchor tag was last active and store its className in a variable called active. On the next click outside on the body the last clicked element is refocused

```js
var active = null;

$('#cat-tabs a').click(function(evt) {
  active = $(this).attr("class");
});
$('body').click(function(evt) {
 if(active!=null){
  $('a.' + active).focus();
}
   
 });
```

```css
#cat-tabs {
  font-size: 0.96em;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: -14px;
}

#cat-tabs li {
  float: left;
  /* LTR */
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 1px;
}

#cat-tabs a {
  color: #333;
  background: #d1d2d4;
  float: left;
  /* LTR */
  height: 2.2em;
  line-height: 2.2em;
  padding: 0 0.8em;
  text-decoration: none;
  -khtml-border-radius-topleft: 8px;
  -khtml-border-radius-topright: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}

#cat-tabs a:hover,
#cat-tabs a:focus {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #af0c07;
}

#cat-tabs a:hover {
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: 0.3s ease;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

#cat-tabs a:active {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #af0c07;
}

.activeBF {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #af0c07;
}

#cat-tabs li a.active {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #3d3b3c;
  -khtml-border-radius-topleft: 8px;
  -khtml-border-radius-topright: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom: none;
}
body{height:1000px;
width:1000px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="cat-tabs">
  <li><a class="tab1" href="#">Live Music</a></li>
  <li><a class="tab2" href="#">Arts &amp; Theatre</a></li>
  <li><a class="tab3" href="#">Classes &amp; Workshops</a></li>
  <li><a class="tab4" href="#">Health &amp; Fitness</a></li>
  <li><a class="tab5" href="#">Food &amp; Drink</a></li>
  <li><a class="tab6" href="#">Happy Hour</a></li>
</ul>
<div style="height:900px;width:900px;background:#333;">

</div>
```